# node modules deleted. now npm is not installing

Tags: node.js, npm, mern, web-development-server

[image]I deleted the node modules and package.json.lock file in my client side MERN Stack project folder and tried reinstalling the node modules by typing "npm install" command in the terminal. but it's showing me an error. 1. I have tried clearing cache using "npm cache clean --force".
2. I have tried reinstalling npm using "npm install -g npm".
3. I have tried updating the npm using "npm install -g npm@latest".

But nothing works. Please help me resolve this issue. below are my package.json file and the error in my terminal while installing node modules.
[image: error in terminal]

i was expecting that node modules will be reinstalled with all the dependencies mentioned in my package.json file.

Comment: Why would you delete `package.json`?

Comment: I deleted package.json.lock

Comment: You mean `package-lock.json`

Comment: You’ll have to restore from a backup source

Comment: Errors says that you've installed `@material-ui/core` in version `4.12.4`, but one of your other dependencies requires version `1.0.0` or `3.1.0`. Usually it means that you have to upgrade the other dependency

Comment: how do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

NPM changed the way of resolving peer dependencies in [v7](https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/#peer-dependencies), but this new way does not allow conflicting dependencies in the dependency tree. The simplest way to solve this would be to use the `--legacy-peer-deps` option to use the old way of resolving dependencies.

The hard(but better) way to solve it would be to spend some time to update the dependencies in a way that there is no conflicting dependency.